# Connect LaTeX to csv

Tags: bibliographies

I need to insert references and make a bibliography, but I don't have the correct style for BibLaTeX, and I don't have time to make a new one. So I am doing it by hand. I am storing the references in a .csv file. I would like to insert the references automatically. The format of the csv is "key-with-dashes-letters-and-numbers;reference with spaces". Is it possible to make LaTeX search the file with the references and fill the references automatically? So that \command{key} gives the corresponding reference? I've read that LaTeX can connect to MySQL, but since I am the only user and that it aren't that many references, it seems a bit too much to use an entire RDBMS for this. Ideally I would like to continue using a csv file as "database".

An example of the system I am using now is:

```
`C-B-NAME-2005;\bronAuteur{F.}{Name}, ``title'', in \bronAuteur{F.}{Name}, \bronAuteur{F.}{Name} en \bronAuteur{F.}{Name} (eds.), \textit{Title\slash Rest of title}, name, Publisher, 2005, 45-85'
`C-B-NAME-1975;\bronAuteur{F.}{Name} en \bronAuteur{F.}{Name}, \textit{Title}, V, Place, Publisher, 1975, 1167 p.'
When compiling `\command{C-B-NAME-2005}, 50`should give `\bronAuteur{F.}{Name}, ``title'', in \bronAuteur{F.}{Name}, \bronAuteur{F.}{Name} en \bronAuteur{F.}{Name} (eds.), \textit{Title\slash Rest of title}, name, Publisher, 2005, 45-85, 50`
```

(`\bronAuteur` does nothing but change the text to capitals and flip "F. NAME" (footnotes) to "NAME, F." (bibliography))

Comment: You could write a script that converts your csv to `\bibitem`-entries.

Comment: Better write a script converting them to a `.bib` file and use Biblatex. Unless you have very complex needs, you don't need to write a Biblatex style. You just use one.

Comment: The problem is, the style I need to use is given in the assignment. I cannot chose the style I want to use. The booklet defining the style is 146 pages (although smaller than A4), so I would think it is not easily done to create a new style or to make an existing one compliant with the style I need to use. It also seems like it isn't a widely used style, only in in my country and only for one field of study.

Comment: Common, now i am interested. Where can i see the style defining a bibliography on 146 pages? ISO 690 has done it in less than 50 pages. I would do it with less than ten pages.

Comment: You can find it at http://verwijzingen-en-afkortingen.be. It is however in Dutch. The field of study is law: "wetgeving" means legislation, "rechtspraak" is jurisdiction and "rechtsleer" is doctrine.

Comment: I skimmed the first 30 pages and i came to a conclusion: *If Wolter would have wanted, that thing could be much schorter*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that if your bibstyle is so simple that accessing you can write a series of citation commands that access a `.csv` and produce correct output, a `biblatex` style would be pretty simple to do, too (or, in fact, simpler!).

But, to get you started on the `.csv` route, here's a very simple example that you should be able to modify.  Of course, I expect that any bibliographies beyond really small ones will have a(n increasingly) profound effect on compilation time.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-bib.csv}
smith2000, "John Smith", The Title, The Journal, 67.4, 2000, 123--456
jones2000, "Sam Jones", Some Title, Some Journal, 12.1, 2000, 1--40
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,
keys={key,name,title,journal,volume,date,pages}]{bibfile}{\jobname-bib.csv}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{%
  \DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{name},\space
  ``\DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{title},''\space
  \emph{\DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{journal}}\space
  \DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{volume}\space
  (\DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{date}):\space
  \DTLfetch{bibfile}{key}{#1}{pages}%
}

\begin{document}
\parindent 0pt

\mycite{smith2000}

\mycite{jones2000}

\end{document}
```

Note also that the `datatool` docs have a section about how to use `datatool` for bibliographies. It is probably worth reading. (The above example does not rely on it except by accident.)

Comment: Needless to say, I have no idea what "key-ith-dashes-letters-and-numbers;reference with spaces" really means.